# Can Sitecore consume ASP.NET MVC web page functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I have a functionality say 'Booking', which is an independent feature written in ASP.NET MVC application, there are 3 different Sitecore applications wants to use the 'Booking' functionality As-Is!

a. Can I load the Booking functionality in iFrame on Sitecore content page ?

b. What is the best way to implement such common feature across multiple (more than one) Sitecore applications ?

c. Is there any best sample / blogs representing, how to implementing such common functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use and iFrame, but you don't *need* an iFrame.  You can embed the application into the Sitecore AppPool and set the path to the application as an exclusion in Sitecore's `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` settings.  This tells Sitecore to let the request "go though to the keeper" as it were - and the application will behave as it otherwise would without intervention.

It might be better, however, to try to embed this application into a CSHTML partial rendering, so that you can track its use with Sitecore and even apply personalisation to the application's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the rich text editor field to add new customn button called **"Insert Iframe"** and you can provide **Url**, **width** and **height** for Iframe, in this way you can use this field with different sitecore applications, checkout this link :

https://superruub.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/sitecore-rich-text-editor-custom-button-insert-iframe/